# Event based triggering of a Pig job

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-pig

I have a system which ingests application log data into Hadoop using Flume. I am indexing this data using Elasticsearch by running a Pig script to load data from Hadoop into ES. Now, I need to automate this task such that every time a new line gets appended, the script should be triggered, or whenever it is triggered it loads only the newly written lines. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: can you post what DB you are using??

Comment: Right now the files are in HDFS. I am using elasticsearch-hadoop jar file for uploading records to ES.

Comment: Take a look at logstash.. it might b useful